# How to get online duration of the network device?

Tags: c#, networking

[image: image showing the online duration of network device]

i want my c# program to be able to display the online duration of the network device. i have tried `NetworkInterface` class but it does not have that info.

Comment: WMI Probably Has a Performance Counter somewhere. I looked for 5 minutes, I couldn't find one, but it's probably in a less obvious place.

Comment: Will the DHCP Lease Obtained time is closer to the network duration ?

Comment: To get more details please visit https://codesanitize.com/unlock-c-network-secrets-uncover-adapter-status-isolate-virtual-networks/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting it through RAS (Remote Access Service), by using DotRas (http://dotras.codeplex.com/), that "Provides remote access service (RAS) components for .NET languages like C#, VB.NET, and C++ CLR projects" as stated on the website.

By checking the function RasGetConnectionStatistics ([MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa377499.aspx)) I've found it returns a structure ([RAS_STATS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446723.aspx)) that has the field "dwConnectDuration" in it.

Hopefully DotRas will provide you a easy way to access that function in C#, along with all the data it returns.

References:

http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/484607-bytes-sent-received-network-adapter
http://channel9.msdn.com/forums/TechOff/69065-Creating-a-RAS-connection-with-C/

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you must find this network interface device. You can do this by using the **GetAllNetworkInterfaces()**.Now, you have a network interface. After, the network interface send this methot.

```
static void getCurrentNicLifeTime(NetworkInterface adapter)
    {
        IPInterfaceProperties adapterProperties = adapter.GetIPProperties();

        UnicastIPAddressInformationCollection uniCast = adapterProperties.UnicastAddresses;

        if (uniCast.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation uni in uniCast)
            {
                DateTime when;
                when = DateTime.UtcNow + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(uni.AddressValidLifetime) - TimeSpan.FromSeconds(864000);
                when = when.ToLocalTime();

                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime() - when);
            }
        }
    }
```

You can also examine [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipinterfaceproperties.unicastaddresses(v=vs.110).aspx) example.

Comment: AddressValidLifetime gets the number of seconds remaining during which this address is valid i.e An Int64 value that specifies the number of seconds left for this address to remain assigned. Not sure why this provides a solution for the duration i.e. how long the connection has been active for?

Answer (score 1):

First Add reference from Network List Manager 1.0 Type Library. Here you can change date as per timezone

```
    var manager = new NetworkListManager();
    var connectedNetworks = manager.GetNetworks(NLM_ENUM_NETWORK.NLM_ENUM_NETWORK_CONNECTED).Cast<INetwork>();
    foreach (var network in connectedNetworks)
    {
        if (network.IsConnected)
        {
          network.GetTimeCreatedAndConnected(out uint _, out uint _, out uint 
          pdwLowDateTimeConnected, out uint pdwHighDateTimeConnected);

          DateTime networkConnectedTime = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc((long) 
        (((ulong)pdwHighDateTimeConnected << 32) | pdwLowDateTimeConnected));

        TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Now.Subtract(networkConnectedTime);

        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + network.GetName() + " NetworkDuration : {0} day(s) {1}:{2}:{3}", diff.Days, diff.Hours, diff.Minutes, diff.Seconds);
             }
 }
```